# Vue - How to send data array to Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, express, vuejs3

```
{
    "product": [
        {
            "product_ID": "test",
            "productDetail": "test",
            "income_ID": "6297343ec4cc7b1ca85521ba"
        },
        {
            "product_ID": "test",
            "productDetail": "test",
            "income_ID": "6297343ec4cc7b1ca85521ba"
        }
    ]
}
```

this my data array I used axios send data to express and mongodb but it's not working

and this my express code to save data in mongodb

```
quotationRoute.route('/incomeProduct').post((req, res, next) => {

    var newProduct = new Qot({
        product:product.req.body.product,
        
    })
    newProduct.save(err => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                title: 'error',
                error: 'error'
            })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            title: 'signup success',
            id: newProduct._id

        })
    })
```

Comment: Where/what is the problem?

Comment: when I send data it won't save

Comment: could you show us the `Qot` schema, and if the save method is throwing an error show the error too.

Comment: const QuaotationSchema = new Schema({

  productDetail: String,
  productQyt: String,
  productPrice: String,
  productUnit: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  income_ID: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Business'},
  product_ID: String,


})